# Mysql Workbench error "system error:61"

Tags: mysql

I have mysql installed several months ago. However I do remember using mysql workbench successfully at one point of time. Today I try launching it and get following error

Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 61

Answer (score 8):

open /etc/mysql/my.cnf in a text editor and try changing:

```
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

to

```
#bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

and then restart MySQL.

Comment: I don't have my.cnf file in that location. is that normal. I am using centos.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the connection method: Local Socket/Pipe.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use the MySQL Workbench and connect through an SSH tunnel, you will get this error when your SSH connection does not complete successfully (e.g. improper host, password, key file, etc)

A good way to trouble shoot this is to separately test the the ssh connection from the machine you are trying to connect from and establish that you can do so succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem.I fix this below:
3306 port may be occupied by other process, so mysql change the port to 3307(or nearly other port 3308...).So when you connect,change the port to 3307 and try