# Failed to connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1 in MySQL Workbench. System error 61

Tags: mysql, database, connection, mamp, mysql-workbench

I'm running into a little trouble with MySQL Workbench.
This is the situation, I'm developing a database to query it remotely from Android devices. This is the first time I use MySQL Workbench, so I've followed this tutorial:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/visual-database-creation-with-mysql-workbench/

I have no problem creating the EER diagram and generating the SQL script. The problem comes when I try to connect to a MySQL server. I get this error:

"***Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root. Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 61***"

http://img101.imageshack.us/i/capturadepantalla201104i.png/ (if the link stops working tell me)

I've also tried using the Local Socket/Pipe connection method with the MAMP Socket in '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock', but it gives the same error. And I've also tried using MAMP port 8889 but still nothing.

So anyone knows how to fix it? And another question, can I connect from my Android device to my laptop(where the database is placed) without using MAMP? MySQL needs MAMP to serve queries? And the last thing, am I going into the right way? Or should I do it other way?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql Workbench error "system error:61"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210624/mysql-workbench-error-system-error61)

Comment: It's the same code error, but I already tried that proposed solution before and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sure that Mysql process is running in your system. not sure in MAC but in windows it'called  mysqld.exe

well take a look

http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/124371

Comment: The command used in the link to check the mysql processes shown that there were mysql processes running, but the mysql server wan't running properly. Now I've installed the latest version or mysql and it works fine... So thank you very much for the help!!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, but part of your question is what fixed it for me:

1. Set connection = Local Socket/Pipe
2. Set socket path = "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock" (for me - I got the path from my MySQL log upon initialisation)

Running: MBP, OSX 10.8.3 (Mountain Lion), MAMP Pro

Can't really fathom any further what your issue may be, but perhaps double check your DB is properly initialised. But, perhaps this helps someone else :)

Answer (score 2):

I typed: sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start 
into the terminal and it started the MySQL server successfully and I was able to connect to MYSQL workbench.

Comment: I have mysql.server but when I run your command line, my computer says mysql.server:command not found

Answer (score 1):

Most commonly happens when **database/server** is not running. You need to check your server, or restart it. You can do so if you have mysql workbench under server administration. Check your manual for restarting or starting the server.

Answer (score 1):

On osx 10.6 using mamp pro I solved this by `allowing network access` in the `MySQL` tab from the home window. Hope it saves someone the pain too

Answer (score 0):

When trying to use the MySQL Workbench and connect through an SSH tunnel, you will get this error when your SSH connection does not complete successfully (e.g. improper host, password, key file, etc)

A good way to trouble shoot this is to separately test the the ssh connection from the machine you are trying to connect from and establish that you can do so successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing MySQL and running it as the admin. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

After making above improvement such as checking if `mysql service` is running or not, you just need to give  a small password while creating connection, it is `' '` or 1 time press on space-bar in case of GUI or workbench. 
After which you just need to validate your machine with server (validated HOST).
For that purpose click on `'New Server Instance'` and it will configure `server/HOST` on your behalf itself.

I have done this *successfully* just a few couple of minutes ago. My workbench software is able to show all `pre-installed` databases etc now.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! On a mac just go to spotlight search on the top right of the screen and type Mysql. Turn it on.

Comment: click on Mysql under system preferences and turn on MySql server.