# workbench: Failed to Connect to MySQL at

Tags: mysql, virtual-machine, mysql-workbench, vagrant

I am using VM for development.

when I connect from ssh command line it is working fine but for mysqlworkbench can not connect.

when I click test connection it returns following thing. I don't know what does that (61) means.

[image]

can anybody please save my day.

many thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210624/mysql-workbench-error-system-error61

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to choose "Standard TCP/IP over SSH" connection method.